# How to install pytorch on Mac OS X?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, pytorch

I get the following error when I try to install pytorch by pip3 on Mac OS X 10.15.6. Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

```
$ pip3 install torch==1.6.0
Collecting torch==1.6.0
  Downloading torch-1.6.0-cp37-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (97.4 MB)
     |███▌                            | 10.8 MB 18 kB/s eta 1:18:39ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 457, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 501, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 210, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 319, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 445, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 339, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name, criterion)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 207, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_criteria_to_update(candidate)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 198, in _get_criteria_to_update
    for r in self._p.get_dependencies(candidate):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 102, in get_dependencies
    for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 101, in <listcomp>
    r
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 252, in iter_dependencies
    requires = self.dist.requires() if with_requires else ()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 234, in dist
    self._prepare()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 221, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 314, in _prepare_distribution
    self._ireq, parallel_builds=True,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 480, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 505, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    self.download_dir, hashes,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 257, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 130, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 163, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 168, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 88, in response_chunks
    decode_content=False,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: Try asking on the github issues page or on one of the pytorch forums. It would probably better received there

Comment: It looks like a network issue

Comment: Which country are you in? You can try to change to a local website hosting mirrors for python packages with `-i`